# Wait for any event of multiple events simultaneously in F#

Tags: events, f#, asynchronous

In F# I know how to wait asynchronously for one event using [`Async.AwaitEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370253.aspx):

```
let test = async {
  let! move = Async.AwaitEvent(form.MouseMove)
  ...handle move... }
```

Suppose I want to wait for either the [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) or the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event. I'd like to have something like this:

```
let! moveOrKeyDown = Async.AwaitEvent(form.MouseMove, form.KeyDown)
```

This function doesn't exist but is there another way to do this?

Comment: Be careful! When you use events created using `Event.xyz` combinators together with `AwaitEvent` and `let!`, you can create a memory leak (when you do the waiting in a loop). You **should always** use `Observable` module instead of `Event` if you want to combine combinators with asynchronous workflows. See my answer for more details...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
let ignoreEvent e = Event.map ignore e

let merged = Event.merge (ignoreEvent f.KeyDown) (ignoreEvent f.MouseMove)
Async.AwaitEvent merged
```

**EDIT:** another version that preserves original types

```
let merged = Event.merge (f.KeyDown |> Event.map Choice1Of2) (f.MouseMove |> Event.map Choice2Of2)
Async.AwaitEvent merged
```

**EDIT 2**: according to comments of *Tomas Petricek*

```
let e1 = f.KeyDown |> Observable.map Choice1Of2
let e2 = f.MouseMove |> Observable.map Choice2Of2
let! evt = Observable.merge e1 e2 |> Async.AwaitObservable
```

*AwaitObservable* primitive can be taken from [here](http://tomasp.net/articles/reactive-talk-london/reactive_fsharp.zip) ('Reactive demos in Silverlight' by Tomas Petricek).

Comment: Could you consider changing the code to use `Observable` instead of `Event`? (Using `Event.xyz` in this scenario can cause leaks - see my answer for more info...)

Comment: You may want to note that `Async.AwaitObservable` is not built into F# and that it's an extension found in "Real-World Functional Programming."

Comment: AwaitObservable is in fsharpx now - https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/Observable.fs

Answer (score 13):

I used an implementation of a method that you use in your sample in the [talk about reactive programming](http://tomasp.net/blog/reactive-talk.aspx) that I had in London (there is a download link at the bottom of the page). If you're interested in this topic, you may find the talk useful as well :-).

The version I'm using takes `IObservable` instead of `IEvent` (so the name of the method is `AwaitObservable`). There are some **serious memory leaks** when using `Event.merge` (and other combinators from the `Event` module) together with `AwaitEvent`, so you should  use `Observable.merge` etc. and `AwaitObservable` instead.

The problem is described in more detail [here](http://tomasp.net/academic/event-chains/event-chains.pdf) (see Section 3 for a clear example). Briefly - when you use `Event.merge`, it attaches a handler to the source event (e.g. `MouseDown`), but it does not remove the handler after you finish waiting using `AwaitEvent`, so the event is never removed - if you keep waiting in a loop coded using asynchronous workflow, you keep adding new handlers (that do not do anything when run).

A simple correct solution (based on what *desco* posted) would look like this:

```
let rec loop () = async {
  let e1 = f.KeyDown |> Observable.map Choice1Of2
  let e2 = f.MouseMove |> Observable.map Choice2Of2
  let! evt = Observable.merge e1 e2 |> Async.AwaitObservable
  // ...
  return! loop() } // Continue looping
```

BTW: You may also want to look at [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Programming-user-interfaces-using-f-sharp-workflows.aspx#s2-waiting-for-events-asynchronously) (based on chapter 16 from my book).

Comment: Interesting. It was actually while reading ch.16 of your book that this question came up. I thought there had to be a way that F# Core somehow provided support for this scenario and it appears it does. Reading through section 3 of the article, I understand what the problem is. What I'm not sure about is whether observables use the backward-referencing technique described in section 6 to prevent memory leaks? Or do they use some other technique?

Comment: @Ronald: Observables use a different technique then the one described in the referenced paper. Briefly (I don't have much time right now) - when you start listening to an observable (e.g. created using `map`), it returns a token that can be used to unregister from the original event source.

Comment: @TomasPetricek - The http://tomasp.net/academic/event-chains/event-chains.pdf link appears to be broken now. Has that PDF been moved elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

In the interest of understanding what's going on I looked up the source code to Event.map, Event.merge and Choice.

```
type Choice<'T1,'T2> = 
    | Choice1Of2 of 'T1 
    | Choice2Of2 of 'T2

[<CompiledName("Map")>]
let map f (w: IEvent<'Delegate,'T>) =
    let ev = new Event<_>() 
    w.Add(fun x -> ev.Trigger(f x));
    ev.Publish

[<CompiledName("Merge")>]
let merge (w1: IEvent<'Del1,'T>) (w2: IEvent<'Del2,'T>) =
    let ev = new Event<_>() 
    w1.Add(fun x -> ev.Trigger(x));
    w2.Add(fun x -> ev.Trigger(x));
    ev.Publish
```

This means our solution is creating 3 new events.

```
async {
    let merged = Event.merge 
                     (f.KeyDown |> Event.map Choice1Of2) 
                     (f.MouseMove |> Event.map Choice2Of2)
    let! move = Async.AwaitEvent merged
}
```

We could reduce this to one event by making a tightly coupled version of this library code.

```
type EventChoice<'T1, 'T2> = 
    | EventChoice1Of2 of 'T1
    | EventChoice2Of2 of 'T2
    with 
    static member CreateChoice (w1: IEvent<_,'T1>) (w2: IEvent<_,'T2>) =
        let ev = new Event<_>()
        w1.Add(fun x -> ev.Trigger(EventChoice1Of2 x))
        w2.Add(fun x -> ev.Trigger(EventChoice2Of2 x))
        ev.Publish
```

And here is our new code.

```
async {
    let merged = EventChoice.CreateChoice form.MouseMove form.KeyDown
    let! move = Async.AwaitEvent merged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `Event.map` and `Event.merge`:

```
let eventOccurs e = e |> Event.map ignore
let mouseOrKey = Event.merge (eventOccurs frm.MouseMove) (eventOccurs frm.KeyDown)
```

Then you can use `Async.AwaitEvent` with this new event.  If `MouseMove` and `KeyDown` had the same type, you could skip the `Event.map` step and just directly merge them.

**EDIT**

But at Tomas points out, you should use the `Observable` combinators in preference to the `Event` ones.

Comment: This works but now I loose the ability to do anything with the event properties because the event is of type `unit`. Maybe I need to take an entirely different approach but I'm not sure what.

Comment: you can map event args on Choice (or some another type) instead of ignoring it. I've edited my answer to include sample for this version