# Async and Events

Tags: events, asynchronous, f#

I have a function that will do some stuff asynchronously, but doesn't expose an async and instead will call a callback with the result when finished. I want to turn that into an async, and have come up with this code, but doesn't seem quite right. Any better way to do it?

```
async { 
    let ev = Event<_>()
    someAsyncExternalCodeThatWillCallTheCallbackWhenDone(fun value -> ev.Trigger value)
    let! value = Async.AwaitEvent(ev.Publish)
    return value 
}
```

Any advantage of using an Observable or a ManualResetEvent instead of an Event in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idiomatic solution in this case is to use `Async.FromContinuations`:

```
Async.FromContinuations(fun (cont, econt, ccont) ->
  someAsyncExternalCodeThatWillCallTheCallbackWhenDone(cont))
```

The `FromContinuations` function also lets you handle exceptions (call `econt` if an exception occurs) or cancellation (and you can see it as the *basic* way to create async computations).

That said, I don't think there is anything wrong with using events. The code with events implements pretty much the same logic (I think) but in a more complex way.

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701861/wait-for-any-event-of-multiple-events-simultaneously-in-f still relevant? (referring to your answer to that question, particularly to using Event with AwaitEvent and memory leaks)